# Logback not working for Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, logback

I have a **desktop Java (1.8.0_40) application** in a Maven project. Here is my `pom.xml` for Hibernate and Logback libraries:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <!-- ... -->

    <dependencies>
        <!-- ... -->

        <!-- Bibliotecas de log -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Fim - Bibliotecas de log -->

        <!-- Banco -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ... -->

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And here is my `logback.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="LB_STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level {%thread} [%logger{40}] : %msg%n</pattern>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <!-- ... file appenders -->

    <logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="ALL" />
    <logger name="org.hibernate" level="DEBUG" />

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="LB_STDOUT" level="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="LB_FILE" level="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="LB_FILE_ERRORS" level="ERROR" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

When I run the application, all of my business classes are been logged in the NetBeans console... example:

```
08/04/2015 12:31:50.781 INFO  {AWT-EventQueue-0} [o.repository.RepositorySysPDVImpl] : Inicializando lista de produtos para exportação.
```

But **Hibernate logs are been ignored.**

Is there something I'm missing? I have a similar `logback.xml` file for a Web Application and it works, but for this Desktop Application, it's not.

Answer (score 4):

I found the "problem".

`log4j` was being imported with a lib inside my `pom.xml`. After removing it, all the other libs started to use **Logback** as the default logging lib.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mandrillapp.wrapper.lutung</groupId>
    <artifactId>lutung</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.4</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```